# Sonar properties with environment variables

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Can we refer to environment variables in `sonar-project.properties`? For example:

```
sonar.libraries=${env:WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.jar
```

The environment variables are useful because library dependency location may be different across different machines and OS.

When I analyzed my project with Sonar Runner, I encountered the error below.

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to resolve path "${env:WL_HOME}/server/lib"
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.resolvePath(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:463)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.getLibraries(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:449)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.validateDirectories(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:299)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.defineProject(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:131)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.execute(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:114)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.projectBootstrap(ProjectScanContainer.java:95)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:72)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:90)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:56)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:44)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:175)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:163)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:414)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.resolvePath(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:461)
        ... 34 more
```

My environment:

- SonarQube 4.3.2
- SonarQube Runner 2.4
- jdk1.7.0_65
- Windows 7 Pro 32-bit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Environment variable support in sonar-project.properties has been added to SonarQube Scanner CLI 2.9, see [SQSCANNER-9](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SQSCANNER-9).

The environment variables must begin with the prefix `env.` not `env:`

After upgrading SonarQube to 2.9+ and updating your property to the correct syntax  it should analyse your project correctly. Example of correct environment variable usage:

```
sonar.libraries=${env.WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.jar
```

Answer (score 7):

This is not supported yet. You can vote for the following ticket: [SONARUNNER-76](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARUNNER-76)

Comment: codehaus.org no longer exists. Anyone have an updated link to the SONARRUNNER JIRA?

Answer (score 5):

This is still not supported. As a workaround, I use the `-D` option to set variable properties.

```
usage: sonar-runner [options]

Options:
 -D,--define <arg>     Define property
```

For the OP, this could be

```
sonar-runner -D sonar.libraries=${WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.jar
```

Comment: Hmmm... If I use `-D` argument, then everything inside `sonar-project.properties` file is ignored. I thought the command-line supplied property/value pair will override.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me using sonnarqube plugin in Gradle:

property "sonar.java.libraries", [System.getenv('ANDROID_HOME')+'/platforms/android-23/android.jar']